# Calling two .Call (Rcpp) function in the same R session in MAC OSX

Tags: c++, r, macos, rcpp

I am facing a strange problem. The program works fine on a linux machine but on a MAC OSX. The R program crashes. I have 2 R functions. They call two different C++ functions as follows. I call these R functions from a third R function. While using a mac the results from the first 
.call(main1)function are generated and when the other .call(main2) is called the program crashes saying input parameters not found. When I run them the two functions independently in  in separate R sessions they work fine. I just can't figure out the exception. It works fine on a linux machine

```
> getResults()
{
   funct1() {
       .call(main1, s1, s2)
   }
   funct2() {
       .call(main2, s1, s2)
   }
}
```

Comment: In title you say`.Call`. In the body you say `.call`. I don't think those would be synonymous in R.

Comment: @DWin That is yet another way of saying 'your non-reproducible examples sucketh' ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not a reproducible example so we cannot offer specifics. Can you provide a *full* example exhibiting your issue?

In general, you can do any one of

- use 'Rcpp attributes' and `sourceCpp()` and just declare your two functions
- call `cppFunction()` twice, or `cxxfunction()` from the inline package
- write a package

Comment: Thank you Dirk the prompt response. Just wanted to know why the program works on a linux machine but crashes on a OSX platform.

Comment: I did try what you recommended, it does work for that particular sample package then probably it is not an operating system issues probably it is my code

Comment: That is indeed the most likely reason. But until you show code nobody can help.

Comment: I have not been able to find a solution yet. I already have a package. But some how the second .Call always crashes(even if the same function is called)in the same R session on OSX.

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify -- make it two simple functions that not allocate or create new objects. Start from something that works.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked. After calling my function I called the repp_hello_world .Call function. It seems that the objects being passed from R to C++ are not being passed some how in MAC only. Sorry for bugging you again and again